# Is my system vulnerable to Apple's new password-in-clear-text bug?

Tags: macos, security, password, user-account

> [With the latest Lion security update, Mac OS X 10.7.3, Apple has accidentally turned on a debug log file outside of the encrypted area that stores the user’s password in clear text.](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/apple-security-blunder-exposes-lion-login-passwords-in-clear-text/11963)

How can I determine whether my system if affected by this issue? If so, can I work around it, and also determine which users’ passwords have been exposed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the article linked in the question:

> Anyone who used FileVault encryption on their Mac prior to Lion, upgraded to Lion, but kept the folders encrypted using the legacy version of FileVault is vulnerable. FileVault 2 (whole disk encryption) is unaffected.

The password shows up in `/var/log/secure.log`. To look for it, log in as an Administrator, open Terminal.app and run

```
sudo grep -i passwordAsUTF8String /var/log/secure.log
```

Have a look at the result (if any) to see whether passwords appear in plain text.

---

For additional information see

- [Apple update to OS X Lion exposes encryption passwords](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/05/06/apple-update-to-os-x-lion-exposes-encryption-passwords/)
- [Apple Legacy Filevault Hole](http://cryptome.org/2012/05/apple-filevault-hole.htm)

Comment: And if my significant other doesn't really remember what he did on his laptop, how can I confirm if it is affected or not?

Comment: Is FileVault enabled for his home directoy (have a look System Preferences)?

Comment: Yes, FileVault is enabled. How do I know if it was migrated and kept to a legacy version?